# How to handle citrus cutting blossoming

Tags: citrus, cuttings

I had to remove a fairly uncommon (maybe ugli fruit), but dying citrus tree last year, and took some cuttings - 1 of which appears to be growing.

My concern is that it is tiny (cutting is maybe 15cm high), blossoming but has no leaves.  How do I encourage it to grow? If I don't do anything will the blossoms drop and leaves take their place?

[image: citrus tree cutting]